# ELasticsearch - Kibana dates and timepicker not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to using the ELK stack and running into the following problem ->

I have a CSV file with the following format ->

"string1" , "string2" , "string3" , "2016-06-26" , "string4"

My mapping in elasticsearch creates properties for strings 1,2,3 and 4 of type string and a property of type date with the following format : yyyy-MM-dd"

My date filter looks like ->

```
date {
match => ["Timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
target => "@timestamp"
}
```

So far all is good .

I can see in Kibana that @timestamp is as expected , ( same as Timestamp )

However , I can't seem to get the following sorted out ->

(1) My date is off by one . For example , if my date string in my csv file is 2016-06-26 , it shows up as 2016-06-25 in elasticsearch/kibana .

(2) The timepicker in Kibana doesn't work . Even assuming dates off by one , if i filter for records between 1 may 2016 to 31 may 2016 I would have expected it to show something . But this filtering does not work .

note that i am able to build visualizations and dashboards and all the records get indexed .
Any help highly appreciated .

Comment: 1. Have you considered timezones?
2. For timepicker, did you choose @timestamp as the `time-field name` in settings?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you considered timezones?
2. For timepicker, did you choose `@timestamp` as the `time-field name` in settings?

Comment: Haven't done either. Can you tell me how to set the time-field ? Also the date string in the CSV does not have any timezones...it's just a string like 2016-10-26...how to add time zones ?

Comment: for late visitors, the time-field can only be set when creating an index pattern - that means that if you have already have an index pattern, all your visualizations, dashboards and scripted fields will be lost, so be careful.